# Is the SSH SFTP subsystem required on the managed nodes for Ansible to work?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, ansible

When I run:

```
ansible all -a "/bin/echo hello" -u myuser
```

I get back:

```
mydomain.myhost.com | FAILED => failed to open a SFTP connection (Channel closed.)
```

The SFTP subsystem is disabled on the managed node I'm trying to connect to.

**Is SFTP required on the managed nodes?** The Ansible docs don't mention SFTP specifically: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_installation.html#managed-node-requirements

I tried setting [this value](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#scp-if-ssh) in ansible.cfg:

```
scp_if_ssh=True
```

...but it had no effect. (Thanks to Fred the Magic Wonder Dog for [the suggestion](https://serverfault.com/a/582190/38226).)

I also ensured that my non-interactive shell doesn't produce any output [as suggested here](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#2.9).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Copied `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` to `~/.ansible.cfg`
2. Edited  `~/.ansible.cfg`.
3. Changed `#scp_if_ssh = False` to `scp_if_ssh = True`
4. Added `ssh_args =` to `[ssh_connection]` section.
5. Ran my command with `-c SSH` flag

Thanks to [Fred the Magic Wonder Dog](https://serverfault.com/a/582190/38226) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: better to have code segment for your settings (`ansible.cfg`), i noticed `scp_if_ssh=True` shall be put below `[ssh_connection]`, `ssh_args` is optional depends on each configuration.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, ansible depends on being able to transfer files to the remote machine. It uses sftp to do this by default. You can override this to use scp using

```
scp_if_ssh
Occasionally users may be managing a remote system that doesn’t have SFTP enabled. If set to True, we can cause scp to be used to transfer remote files instead:

scp_if_ssh=False
There’s really no reason to change this unless problems are encountered, and then there’s also no real drawback to managing the switch. Most environments support SFTP by default and this doesn’t usually need to be changed.
```

The above information was taken from this page:

http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#openssh-specific-settings

Comment: I uncommented "scp_if_ssh = True", but it had no effect.  I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `connection: paramiko`. It works even when both `stfp` and `scp` are not avilable. Under the hood, it uses the same ssh as the "normal" ssh, so even `~/.ssh/config` will apply.

Alternatively, the connection type can be specified via env variable, on the command line via `-c` switch, and in `ansible.cfg`.

For example:

```yml
- hosts: all
  connection: paramiko
  tasks:
    command: echo ok
```

or

```
ansible all -c paramiko -a "/bin/echo hello" -u myuser
```

If paramiko is not installed, but may have to install it via pip (`pip install paramiko`) or using your distributive-specific package manager (`apt install python3-paramiko` if you're using ansible with python3, check using `ansible --version`)